# design a responsive table with collapse and expand rows in react

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, bootstrap-4, sass, user-experience

I want to design a table that can expand and collapse rows to show data when the row is clicked inner table appears. clicking again hides it again.

> An example or guidance would be much helpful

, I'm using react, reactstrap and bootstrap v4.4 in this project

Comment: check out this: https://rb.gy/eseafa

Comment: Depends a little on your datastructure, but I'd create a row component that has an attribute `colapsed` which is toggled with the button the first row and if the component is not colapsed, show all data. For more detailed help you need to provide more detailed information.